# Exclude Character in Google Analytics via Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation

I'm trying to exclude (in a Goal) a character in a regex in Google Analytics.

Basically, I have two pages with the following URL:

```
/signup/done/b
/signup/done/bp
```

Note that both might have UTM parameters after in some results as well

I am trying to measure only `/done/b`

The Regex I had was the following, but it includes both strings:

```
(/signup/done/plan/b)
```

When I changed it (and verified it in an external regex tester) I got 0 results, so the `/b/` was also not included.

```
(/signup/done/plan/b[^p])
```

Comment: Use `\/signup\/done\/plan\/b$`

Comment: Thanks. Technically there's an unlimited possibility as there might be UTM codes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This regex would handle the case where the URL ends with `/b` or if there are query parameters:

```
/signup/done/b($|\?.*)
```

So examples of **converting** URLs would be:

```
/signup/done/b
/signup/done/b?utm_campaign=test&utm_medium=display
/signup/done/b?query=value
```

Examples of **non-converting** URLs would be:

```
/signup/done/bd
/signup/done/b/something
```

Comment: Good answer.  Avi, you can verify the regex syntax here:  http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester